# How to make simple .file like a Gherking .feature file?

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber, karate, gherkin

[image]

i did something when was creating new feature file and all feature files changed to simple .file format
how can i return it back to gherkin format file?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by running CLT + ALT + S in Intellij, then Editor -> File Types and scrolled to the Text and inside I found .feature and deleted it from there.then I scroll up and find the cucumber scenario script and add the *.feature file there

[image]